# Allowing the end user a second chance?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a text game in C# and basically.

```
if (DoorHallwayMB1 == "door")
{
   Console.WriteLine("You open the rusty door to reveal a janitor's closet, you quickly stock up \non ammo, and return to the Hangar.");
}

if (DoorHallwayMB1 == "corridor")
{
   Console.WriteLine("You walk down the corridor and find some ammo forr your pistol. You return to the hangar");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("invalid. Make sure you type either 'corridor' or 'door'");
}
```

Notice that if the else statement is reached, the program terminates. How do I make it so that it goes back to the start of the if statement?

Comment: Note that you need `else if` for corridor branch, otherwise user will get "invalid. Make sure ..." if he or she types `door`.

Answer (score 2):

Just another option, You can also use `switch`:

```
bool isValid = false;
string DoorHallwayMB1 = string.Empty;
while (!isValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What will it be?");
    DoorHallwayMB1 = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (DoorHallwayMB1)
    {
        case "door":
            Console.WriteLine("You open the rusty door to reveal a janitor's closet, you quickly stock up \non ammo, and return to the Hangar.");
            isValid = true;
            break;
        case "corridor":
            Console.WriteLine("You walk down the corridor and find some ammo forr your pistol. You return to the hangar");
            isValid = true;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("invalid. make sure you type either 'corridor' or 'door'");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful. The inner `break`s break from the switch, not the loop.

Comment: I thought he just wanted an infinite loop, and evaluate DoorHallwayMB1 at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: No he wants to loop until he gets a valid response.

Comment: Sorry about that. Using `while` loop and `switch`.

Comment: You may want to remove the `//exit loop` comments from the source since it is not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You want a loop:

```
bool valid = false;
while(!valid)
{
    //get input
    if(/*valid input*/)
    { 
        //do whatever
        valid = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop:

```
while( true )
{
    //DoorHallwayMB1 = ....
    if (DoorHallwayMB1 == "door")
    {
       Console.WriteLine("You open the rusty door to reveal a janitor's closet, you quickly stock up \non ammo, and return to the Hangar.");
       break; //exit loop
    }
    if (DoorHallwayMB1 == "corridor")
    {
       Console.WriteLine("You walk down the corridor and find some ammo forr your pistol. You return to the hangar");
       break; // exit loop
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("invalid. make sure you type either 'corridor' or 'door'");
    }
}
```

Comment: actually... it just writes "invalid. make sure you type either 'corridor' or 'door'" infinitely...

Comment: @user2730877 then the way you are getting the input is incorrect. Do you see my line that is commented out? You need to get the new value of `DoorHallwayMB1` there.

Comment: @user2730877 Yes, you need to actually take input from the user. Read the documentation on Console.Read or Console.ReadLine

Comment: I don't understand... What value should 'DoorHallwayMB1' be?

Comment: @user2730877 aren't you getting it from the user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a loop with a suitable exit mechanism. For example

```
bool exitCondition=false;
while (true)
{
    // your code which also sets exitConditon
    if(exitCondition) {break;}
}
```

Comment: Question: If you are going to put the `if( exitCondition ){ break; }` at the end of the loop, why not just use it as the conditional: `while( !exitCondition )`